# Parallel Programming Clarification and Concurrent Programming

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, terminology

I've been reading up on parallel and concurrent programming, and there are two things that I still have not found answers to and still confused about.

1) In some places I read that parallel programming allows multiple processes to be executed simultaneously by taking advantage of multiple CPUs, while it other places I read that it does this by taking advantage of multiple cores. Exactly which is right? To my understanding the core is part of the CPU, so it's not possible for both definitions to be valid (unless I'm missing something).

2) I have a basic understanding of how concurrent programming works, but I fail to see why it would be faster for two processes to be executed concurrently rather than sequentially. For example, if there are two threads consisting of four computations that require the same amount of time to be processed:

Thread A: A1 A2 A3 A4

Thread B: B1 B2 B3 B4

Concurrent execution of the threads could possibly result in the following execution: A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3 A4 B4. But how would that be any faster than if the two threads were sequentially executed: A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4? Both methods of execution require eight total computations, which means that the total time would be the same.

Comment: For number 2) think about I/O intensive applications. If one thread is waiting for I/O, then other threads may execute while the needed I/O operation does not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a two-core ([multi-core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core)) CPU (or two one-core CPUs), each thread could run on a separate core. Assuming no synchronization is required between the two threads, they can both run at the same time (i.e. each core runs 4 steps, at the same frequency - and thus half the time - a single core would run 8 steps).

A multi-core CPU can be generally (the devil is in the details) thought of as multiple CPUs on a single chip: each core, independent of where it is located, can execute a program simultaneously.

For instance, a system with 2x Intel i7-47xx (4 cores) processors has 8 (2x4) physical cores. (And with [Hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), there are 16 virtual cores..)